# Setting default for undefined hash values

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash whose values are mostly integers, but some are undefined. I would like to set all of these undefined values to zero, either with a `for` loop or, preferably, with a more elegant method. Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: don't worry about "elegant", just write code that makes sense to you

Comment: @ysth imho, when OPs asking for "elegant" thats mean, _he knows how to write it in own way, but want learn an more effective way_. +1 for those questions :)

Comment: This really should be done when your hash is built in the first place.

Comment: @jm666: no, I think it often means elegant, under some stylistic guide other than what makes sense to the person actually writing the code.  and in the cases where it means what you say, your "effective" really means "prematurely optimized"

Comment: @ysth ;) Agree with _prematurely_ optimized, but one good way how to learn any more "effective" style is asking more experienced programmers. E.g. Ikgegami is known for his "exremelly" optimized (often nearly write only) code in answers, but i'm happy because learned much new "things"... ;)

Comment: learning is always good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both methods are using foreach,

```
for my $key (keys %hash) {
  $hash{$key} //= 0;

}

$_ //= 0 for values %hash;
```

`//=` operator test if variable is undefined and assign new value when it is.